# erro de envio de e-mail com phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Galera estou tentando mandar um e-mail para várias pessoas dentro de um array chamado `$destinatario`.

Para isso criei uma função chamada `envia_email`.

Porém estou tendo o seguir erro:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function AddBCC() on string in
```

Que ocorre na linha:

```
$email->AddBCC($email, $name);
```

Não sei o que pode ser. Segue meu código abaixo.

```
        <?php

    $destinatario = array(
        'person1@domain.com' => 'Person One',
        'person1@domafdsin.com' => 'Perqweson One',
    );

    function envia_email($destinatario,$titulo,$texto) {

        // Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php localizado na pasta phpmailer
        include("Modules/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

        // Instanciamos a classe
        $email = new PHPMailer();

        // Informamos que a classe ira enviar o email por SMTP
        $email->isSMTP();

        // Configuração de SMTP
        $email->Host = "xxxxxxx";
        $email->SMTPAuth = true;
        $email->SMTPDebug = false;
        $email->Port = "587";
        $email->Username = "xxxxxxx";
        $email->Password = "xxxxxxx";

        // Remetente da mensagem
        $email->From = "xxxxxxx";
        $email->FromName = "xxxxxxx";

        // Destinatário do email
        foreach($destinatario as $email => $name) {
            $email->AddBCC($email, $name);
        }

        // Iremos enviar o email no formato HTML
        $email->IsHTML(true);

        // Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
        $email->Subject = "$titulo";

        $email->Body = "$texto";

        // Envia o e-mail
        $email->Send();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tu está sobrescrevendo a variável `$email` dentro do laço **foreach** é só trocar o nome de uma delas que deve funcionar.

function envia_email($destinatario,$titulo,$texto) {

```
    // Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php localizado na pasta phpmailer
    include("Modules/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

    // Instanciamos a classe
    $email = new PHPMailer();

    // Informamos que a classe ira enviar o email por SMTP
    $email->isSMTP();

    // Configuração de SMTP
    $email->Host = "xxxxxxx";
    $email->SMTPAuth = true;
    $email->SMTPDebug = false;
    $email->Port = "587";
    $email->Username = "xxxxxxx";
    $email->Password = "xxxxxxx";

    // Remetente da mensagem
    $email->From = "xxxxxxx";
    $email->FromName = "xxxxxxx";

    // Destinatário do email
    foreach($destinatario as $emailToSend => $name) {
        $email->AddBCC($emailToSend, $name);
    }

    // Iremos enviar o email no formato HTML
    $email->IsHTML(true);

    // Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
    $email->Subject = "$titulo";

    $email->Body = "$texto";

    // Envia o e-mail
    $email->Send();
}
```

Comment: não entendi muito bem, tem com postar um exemplo na resposta?

Comment: claro, coloquei na respostá ali.

Comment: hahhahahahahha como não prestei atenção nisso hahah, vlw muito obrigado

Comment: acontece hehe :p